# html form updating with php

Tags: php, mysqli, forms

I am trying to update my phpmyadmin database using the php and html code below: I have been successful in adding a first row of data, but once I try to use the form again I cannot add another row of data unless I delete the previous one I inserted into the database. In short, I can only have 1 row in my database at a time.
Thanks for any help :)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="inserto.php" method="post">

        Customer ID: <input type="number" name="IDc">
            <br/>
        Stock ID: <input type="number" name="IDs">
            <br/>
        Date of Purchase: <input type="date" name="dob">
            <br/>
        Pay status: <input type="text" name="paystatus">
            <br/>
        Price Paid: <input type="text" name="price">
            <br/>
        Discount: <input type="text" name="discount">
            <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>






</body>
</html>


<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jainam_ia");

    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Not connected';
    }

    $IDc=$_POST['IDc'];
    $IDs=$_POST['IDs'];
    $dob=$_POST['dob'];
    $paystatus=$_POST['paystatus'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $discount=$_POST['discount'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_orders (IDc, IDs, Date_of_purchase, Pay_Status, Price_Paid, Discount) VALUES ('$IDc', '$IDs', '$dob', '$paystatus', '$price', '$discount')";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        echo 'Order not added';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Order added';
    }

    header("refresh:2; url=indexo.html");

?>
```

Comment: fyi: "phpmyadmin database" no such thing, phpmyadmin is just a php script,

Comment: your approach, and both answers below leave you open to SQL injection attacks. before putting the code in to production please fix that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: This is just a school project I am working on, nothing that will actually go into production. Thank you for the advice, I will look into it anyway :)

Comment: @JainamNiravSHAH12C06S show us your table structure

Comment: it ended up working, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely in your mysql table `tbl_orders` was set column with `primary_key` attribute, but without `auto_increment` attribute.

Example of adding attribute `auto_increment` (you need to change `id` name to your primary key column name):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_orders MODIFY id int AUTO_INCREMENT;
```